# diff two versions of a file that reside in different directories

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cygwin, csh

I would like to diff two versions of a file that reside in different directories, for example:

```
diff ./dirA/foo.txt ./dirB/foo.txt
```

I vaguely remember there is a way to write this in a more condensed way, so that the filename appears only once. Something like:

```
diff {./dirA/, ./dirB/}foo.txt
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close. No space.

```
diff dir{A,B}/foo.txt
```

or, in the more likely case that the two folders don't actually have a common substring like that,

```
diff {dir,folder}/foo.txt
```

And, should you want to compare the whole tree, note that `diff` has a recursive (`-r`) option.

Answer (score 2):

You're close:

```
diff {dirA,dirB}/foo.txt
```

that should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

So close.

```
diff {./dirA/,./dirB/}foo.txt
```

or

```
diff ./{dirA,dirB}/foo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
diff ./dirA/foo.txt dirB
```

is this what you were thinking of?